# Simplifying/reducing a simple equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation that I would like to simplify/reduce to a simpler form. 
Can anyone help me out solving this problem?
Thanks in advance for yout help!

$$z = -\frac{(1/n)-(1/y)}{(1/n)}$$

Or probably the correct way is:

$$z = -\frac{(\frac{1}{n})-(\frac{1}{y})}{(\frac{1}{n})}$$

Can this cut both $(1/n)$ to something like this:

$$z = (1/y)$$

Comment: No. You can apply distribute property.

Comment: To reiterate an above point,  $\frac{x+y}{x}\neq y$ in general.  $\frac{1+2}{1}=3\neq 2$ for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "simplest form" of an equation is a matter of opinion, so maybe other people will tell you something else.

You have the equation
$$z = -\frac{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{y}}{\frac{1}{n}}.$$
You can multiply both numerator and denominator of the fraction on the right-hand-side by $n$ to get
$$z = -\frac{n\cdot\frac{1}{n} - n\cdot\frac{1}{y}}{n\cdot\frac{1}{n}}.$$
Since $n\cdot\frac{1}{n} = 1$, this is the same as
$$z = -\frac{1-\frac{n}{y}}{1}.$$
Dividing by $1$ doesn't do anything, so I don't have to write it. The equation thus becomes
$$z = -\left(1-\frac{n}{y}\right).$$
Finally, I can clear the paranthesis on the right-hand-side, but since theres a minus sign in front of it, I need to flip the signs inside. I get:
$$z = -1+\frac{n}{y} = \frac{n}{y}-1,$$
where the last equality is just flipping the order of the terms. So $z = \frac{n}{y}-1$, which is much simpler than the original equation.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great help. Providing all the steps used is this approach to get the final result. I still struggle in this matter but i will get there.
Thanks for your time, and for everybody else also.

Answer (score 0):

multiplying denominator and numerator by $$n$$ we get $$-(1-\frac{n}{y})$$

Answer (score 0):

Distribute the negative sign and multiply by $\frac{n}{n}$ which is the same as multiplying by 1. This will give you $$z=\frac{n}{y} -1$$

Comment: Hey, just a small correction. When you multiply through by $y$ in $z = \frac{n}{y}-1$, you get to $zy = n-y$.

Answer (score 0):

The simplification can work in this way:
$$z = -\frac{(\frac{1}{n})-(\frac{1}{y})}{(\frac{1}{n})} =-\frac{(\frac{1}{n})}{(\frac{1}{n})}+\frac{(\frac{1}{y})}{(\frac{1}{n})} = -1+\frac{(\frac{1}{y})}{(\frac{1}{n})}=-1+\frac{n}{y}$$

Comment: Thanks! This as less steps, but I have dificulty following and untherstanding all the steps used because I have dificulteis in this subject.

Comment: I have used the distributive law of multiplication. $\frac{1}{c}(a+b)=\frac{a+b}{c}=\frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c}$

Comment: Thanks for this info and the extra approach on this problem. Thanks!